# Mobile Safari, Web Apps, Site.Manifest and no internet connection

Tags: html, safari, web-applications, manifest

Using HTML5 and the Site.Manifest file, is it at all possible to create a web app that can be added to the iPhone/iPad home screen but have no requirement for an internet connection afterward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Moo, if you still are having this problem, I had to set the mime type of the manifest in my server configuration to  'text/cache-manifest'

Answer (score 0):

yes using cache.manifest. Put all files which should be available offline in the cache.manifest.

See also Apple docs at: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iphone/conceptual/safarijsdatabaseguide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html

Comment: As indicated in my question, I do already have a .manifest file but the web app still checks for remote access before complaining it cannot access the server.